# Do we need [echo] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There's an [echo](/questions/tagged/echo) tag on StackOverflow.

The description is quite vague:

> Simple function outputting text. Exists in script languages.

The usage is quite inconsistent. For example, the question [How to use css style in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201451/how-to-use-css-style-in-php) is not about 'echo' function, only the code uses it.

This one is quite interesting: [Bash printing "\r"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794718/bash-printing-r)
Actually, the tag answers that question :)

Do we need such a tag? Shouldn't it be replaced by more specific ones?

Comment: Burn it, nobody's an expert in `echo`.

Comment: @michaelb958: Quite the opposite, there are a lot of experts in `[echo]` out there...but most of them hang out on warships and submarines.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Ooh, submarine programming!

Comment: **of** of of **course** course course **we** we we **need** need need **echo** echo echo

Comment: @michaelb958: "Need code for making sonar for submarine. But screen does not display ping and echo, whats wrong with code? Please urgent, need to be done on Monday because ship leaves! :("

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be edited to be more specific, it was there because it served a specific purpose. the use of it is just not defined correctly making it vague.

Comment: So what shall be that specific purpose of this tag?

Comment: maybe a voting should be made.

Comment: Count my vote for destroying the tag then.